# Lazy Loading Images and Source Code

Tags: seo, web-development, page-speed, load-time, lazyloading

I have a question in regards to lazy-loading. To improve our site speed, we would like to convert all the images on our website to be lazily loaded.

My question is since the images that are lazily loaded would not appear in the source code when they are not yet brought into view, is this feature would affect the SEO of the website?

I read a couple of threads here but it was a bit too technical for me or the answers were from 4 years ago...

Thank you !!